# Insert multiple values of input fields one column in separate multiple rows using php

Tags: php, html, css, sql-server, twitter-bootstrap

I want to Insert multiple values of input fields one column in separate multiple rows. input is taking multiple values in array as tags. I am using PHP & sql server as database

```
<input class="col-sm-10 tokenfield" style="width:50%;" type="text" placeholder="Enter ID" class="form-control" name="id[]" id="id" required />
```

sql query is

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
foreach( $id as $i){
    $sql = insert into [db].[table] (id,name,phone,message) values ($i,$name,$phone,$message)
}
```

it showing as group values in single row in column of table but i want all values in as different rows values as `id`

Comment: If I got you right you want to add new column for each id inserted input?

Comment: @VüsalHüseynli No new row inserted with multiple values which was entered in input box

Comment: I assume that you are getting comma separated values in **$id** variable. If thats the case then you may want to change your foreach loop like **$ids = explode(',', $id); foreach( $ids as $i)**

Comment: @Bhavikms yes i am getting comma seperated values it gives me an "Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\assign.php" and "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\assign.php" after using explode

Comment: If it's comma separated values than datatype should be string only. Alternatively you can explicitly convert value into string.

Comment: @Bhavikms Yes it is string only! i have taken `id` as varchar and serial number `sno` as my primary key in database

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code which should work. (Convert datatype as needed if require.)

```
$postValue = $_POST['id']; // comma separated values
$ids = explode(',', $postValue); // List of ids

//Loop through each id and prepare SQL statement
foreach($ids as $id){
    $sql = "insert into [db].[table] (id,name,phone,message) values ('$id','$name',$phone,'$message')";
}
```

sample screenshot:
[image]

Comment: not working for me!

Comment: Try this if datatype of your id is varchar: $sql = insert into [db].[table] (id,name,phone,message) values ((string)$id,$name,$phone,$message)

Comment: I have tried this but same error! & yes my id is varchar

Comment: Can you please provide schema of your table?

Comment: sno- int, id - varchar, name - varchar, phone - int, message - varchar

Comment: Can you print the value of $postValue variable and post here?

Comment: input1,input2,input3 these are tag seperated values in and i am using tokenfield cdn for it and it come in table id as input1,input2,input3 in same row in column id but i want this input in different rows 
like 
sno   |  id  |

Comment: I just edited my answer, please have a look

Comment: i had already applied but not working yet Ok i ll check